# Record add/show/delete for file functions not working

Tags: c, file, function

The question's title pretty much explains the situation. I am not used to using files and associated commands (such as fseek, fwrite, etc).

Anyhow, the following program must simulate a menu, and present the user with a choice of either adding, editing, deleting or showing records for a file. It is a rather simplistic task, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
 #include <stdio.h>


typedef struct{
 int code;
 char description[100];
 int volume;
}product;



int main() {



int pick =0, i;
product *p;
FILE *filePtr;

void add(FILE *filePtr, product* p);
void removal(FILE *filePtr, product* p);
void show(FILE *filePtr, product* p);
void edit(FILE *filePtr, product* p);
void description(FILE *filePtr, product* p);


if ( ( filePtr = fopen( "stock.dat", "rb+")) == NULL ) {
    printf("The file could not be read");
}
else {


do{
   printf("    ************ MAIN MENU ************\n");
   printf("  ** -------------welcome------------- **\n");
   printf(" **                                      ** \n");
   printf("*  Please select one of the commands below *\n");
   printf("********************************************\n");
   printf("* Press 1 to remove products from the list *\n");
   printf("* Press 2 to change a product's quantity   *\n");
   printf("* Press 3 to add a new product to the list *\n");
   printf("* Press 4 to view product list             *\n");
   printf("* Press 5 to exit the programm             *\n");
   printf("********************************************\n");
   scanf("%d", &pick);

   switch ( pick ) {

   case 1:
      removal(filePtr, p);
    break;

   case 2:
      edit(filePtr, p);
    break;

   case 3:
     add(filePtr, p);
   break;

   case 4:
     show(filePtr, p);
   break;





   default:
      printf("Error! Please enter a correct number");
   break;
 }
 }while (pick != 5);

  }




fclose(filePtr);


return 0;
}


void removal(FILE *fileptr, product * p) {
    int code;


    product empty = { 0, " ", 0 };

    printf("\n\nYou are about to delete a record, please enter the product's code");
    scanf("%d", &code);

    fseek( fileptr, (code - 1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
    fread( &p->code, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);

    if (p->code == 0){
        printf("Product code not found, please retry");
    } else {
        fseek( fileptr, (code -1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);

        fwrite( &empty, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);

        printf("Code was found, product removed successfully\n\n");
    }
}

 void add(FILE *fileptr, product * p){

  int code, quantity;

  printf("You are about to add a new product in the list\n Please input the product's code\n");

  scanf("%d", &code);


  fseek( fileptr, (code-1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
  fread(&code, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);


    fseek(fileptr, (code-1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite( &code, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);

    printf("Now enter the product's remaining quantity");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);

    fseek(fileptr, (quantity-1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite( &quantity, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);





 }


 void edit(FILE *fileptr, product * p){

  int code, volume;

  printf("\nYou are about to edit a existing product's quantity\n Please enter the product's code\n");
  scanf("%d", &code);

  fseek(fileptr, (code -1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
  fread(&code, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);

  if (p->code == 0){
    printf("\nThe code you entered is not in the list, please retry\n");
  }else{
    printf("\nCode found!\n Product's  current quantity is %d", &p->volume);
    printf("\n Please enter the new quantity");
    scanf("%d", &volume);

    p->volume = volume;


    fseek(fileptr, (volume -1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(&volume, sizeof(p), 1, fileptr);

    }


 }


void show(FILE *fileptr, product * p){

 int i=1;


 printf("\n\n\n               ****SHOWING ALL PRODUCTS****\n\n\n");
 printf("PRODUCT CODE      QUANTITY IN STOCK\n");



 while (i<100 && !feof(fileptr)){
    fscanf( fileptr, "%d%d", &p->code, &p->volume);
    printf("%d            %d\n", &p->code, &p->volume);
    fseek(fileptr, (p->code + 1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
    fscanf( fileptr, "%d%d", &p->code, &p->volume);
    i++;
   }
 printf("You may scroll back up to view the list\n\n");

 }
```

To give an idea of what is happening: if the user enters option 4, the program, instead of showing no records, shows random values, but even if the user chooses to add a product (by picking choice 3, which is the add function), it won't be shown later and as a result, can't be deleted even if the user chooses to do so. Again, I'm rather new at programming (I am sure you hear this a lot :P). I had posted a similar question before, but did not get a solution.

**EDIT** I edited a big portion of the code, basically the file opens in binary and now, the struct product p, passes to each function. Problem now supposedly fixed, program run once showing correct values and records, however crashes by itself for uknown reason. Any additional help would be great

Comment: what does your typical `stock.dat` file look like?

Comment: I have edited your question and tried to indent your code.  I was able to do so until the end of the `removal()` function.  Thereafter, the braces no longer match up.  Please take a look at your code.  Also, you need to do a better job of debugging your code so that you present the minimum amount of code here for others to help.

Comment: I had removed blank lines in your code and had indented it properly.  They are all gone now.  More importantly, your code no longer reflects the original question.  You should have left the original code, and added the new code as an edit, or should have opened a new question with the new code.

Comment: Instead of using `!feof(fileptr)`, check the result of `fscanf()` and act accordingly if the return value is `EOF`.

Comment: In many places, code is doing user IO without checking the result of `scanf()` as in `scanf("%d", &code);`.  This is highly prone to problems.  Better to check results.  Best to use `fgets()` and post process the read buffer.

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely a problem with your `show` function...

For starters, make the following changes to it (marked using comment):

```
void show(FILE *fileptr){

    typedef struct{
        int code;
        char description[100];
        int volume;
    } product;

    product p;

    int i=1;

    // removed the re-opening of the file


    printf("\n\n\n               ****SHOWING ALL PRODUCTS****\n\n\n");
    printf("PRODUCT CODE      QUANTITY IN STOCK\n");

    // moved the first fscanf() into the while loop
    while (i<100 && !feof(fileptr)){
        fscanf( fileptr, "%d%d", &p.code, &p.volume);
        printf("%d            %d\n", &p.code, &p.volume);
        fseek(fileptr, (p.code + 1) * sizeof(p), SEEK_SET);
        i++;
    }
    printf("You may scroll back up to view the list\n\n");

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did so, however the original problem still remains, i still cant see what have i done wrong, to make the programm either save the records wrong, or not at all

Comment: try setting a breakpoint at your `fscanf` in the `while` loop; see what is getting stored into `code` and `volume`.  If that's supposed to be empty then you're not reading from the right place in your file.